# How do I call GetLocalResource in another class

Tags: asp.net, localization, code-behind, resx

So I have `Test1.aspx`, `Test1.aspx.vb`. The LocalResource files, in the `App_LocalResources` folder, `Test1.aspx.resx` and `Test1.aspx.es.resx`. I also have a class called `TestTheData.vb` in the `App_Code` folder.

Now what I want to do is call `GetLocalResource("stringObjRes").ToString` in the `TestTheData.vb` class. The method however is not showing up in Intellisense. When I try to type manually, I get the error lines in my code.

I've imported:

- Globalization
- Threading
- Threading.Thread
- Web
- Web.UI.Page.

No luck. So how I am supposed to do this....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems that Local Resources can't be accessed in files that are in the App_Code folder. So I used Global Resources instead.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's 1 year old but I just added the comment if some others are also searching for this:

Your guess is right, you cannot access the Local Resource Object from another class. GetLocalResourceObject only exists within the code of the page, in your case Test1.aspx.vb. If you are calling the class function from your Test1.aspx.vb you could of course retrieve the Local resource from there and then supply it to your TestTheData.vb as a parameter. But if you need the 'stringObjRes' in several places (not only in Test1.aspx) then a global resource is of course preferred. Details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227982(v=vs.100).aspx